# Why most vehicle apps user orange / red color as their theme?

Tags: color, psychology

I was going through multiple car/bike apps across the world and there was striking similarity that most of them use a shade of either red or orange. I wanted to understand the psychological motive behind it.

Answer (score 3):

The color orange is associated with extroversion, enthusiasm, energy and motivation. Moreover, it's quite noticeable. In the context of transport, orange could represent a positive, "adventurous" vibe which evocates traveling, meeting new people and sharing experiences.

Source: http://www.artitudesdesign.com/orange-color-psychology/